# SQL Server and Sybase Linked Server Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sap-ase, linked-server

In SQL Server 2008 using the Sybase 12.5 driver everything works fine but now we had migrated to SQL Server 2012 and Sybase 15 using the 64bit driver it seems that things are broken.

If I test linked server connection it gives me linked server succeeded message but as I visually drill down the catalogs though it lists all of them they show as blank like such

[image]

but the item count is correct as we have that many catalogs in our Sybase.
Another funny thing that I recognized is that when I perform and OPENQUERY it gives me the correct amount of rows and still it is showing empty strings, like such

[image]

I dont have any idea what is happening here and my only clue is this error message when I drill down inside those blank databases.  This exception prompts.

[image]

```
Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES" for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST". The provider supports the interface, but returns a failure code when it is used. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7311)
```

**Any ideas why this might be happening? does anyone know a solution to this?**

Comment: Any opportunity to try only one change? Either use a Sybase 15 driver on the 2008 instance or use the 12.5 driver on 2012? Is the SQL Server box [patched up](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) 11.00.3000 or greater depending on your CU threshold

Comment: Nope my SQL Server is 11.0.2100.  Also I cant use 12.5 as I am running at 64bit arch on 15 has the 64.  Will try this on an 11.00.3000 instance and let you know.

Comment: Same thing in 11.0.3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by restarting my Server, it looks like the Sybase drivers was not fully registered on install.